# Linearly Independent columns and invertibility of transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, transpose

If a matrix $A$ has linearly independent columns, why is $A^TA$ invertible?

I think it has to do with $A^TA$ being square and that $A^TAx$=0 only has the trivial solution, but I don't really know how to explain that properly.

Answer (score 1):

$A^TA$ is not always invertible even if $A$ has full column rank. Counterexample: $A=\pmatrix{1\\ i}$ over $\mathbb C$ or $A=\pmatrix{1\\ 1}$ over $GF(2)$.

Over the reals, $A^TA$ is invertible if $A$ has full column rank. *Hint:* observe that $\|Ax\|^2=x^TA^TAx$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm.